# Clear content of multiple selected items in a div with onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to clear the mutiple selected items of a div as soon as I hit a select button with onChange event as below.

```
<div ng-show="currentDetails.type=='product_available_in_order'">
        <label> Product Filters : </label>
            <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
                <label>Products Group</label>
                <br/>

                <select ng-model="currentDetails.settings.product_filters.group" onChange="clrContentInabc ()">
                    <option value="products">Products</option>
                    <option value="categories">Specific Categories</option>
                                    <option value="collections">Specific Collections</option>
                            </select>


                            <label>Select {{currentDetails.settings.product_filters.group}}</label>

                            <div ng-show="currentDetails.settings.product_filters.group" id="abc">

                            <select ng-model="currentDetails.settings.product_filters[currentDetails.settings.product_filters.group]"
                                              id="e2" multiple="multiple"
                                              style="width: 100%;"
                                              ng-options="option.alias as option.name for option in ComplimentData[currentDetails.settings.product_filters.group]">
                            </select>

                </div>

                     </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                 function clrContentInabc(){

                        WHAT TO DO HERE???

                 }

                </script>

</div>
```

The div "abc" must be set to default value i.e. Blank. I have already used the empty() function but it results in not loading the options of select. I've also tried .val("") or innerHTML,html("") and they all result in not loading the div "abc".

Comment: You are calling `clrContentInabc` and defining `clearContentInabc`

Comment: So, if you want clear the content of a div whose id is 'abc' you can do: `document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: @JOLMOS As I've already said, this statement results in not loading the abc div element. I need another solution.

Comment: Is it the div id='abc' or the select id='e2' that you want to change?

Comment: under div abc, there is a multiple select items (with id e2) that can be added, I want to clear all of them. So you can say I need to clear div abc, because clearing e2 will result in not loading the ng-options in select id e2.